# Htaccess only allow JS and CSS files to be viewed?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to have a htaccess rule that restricts only to allow js and CSS files to be viewed.

I would to do this for everything inside /paymethod/.

So this should be viewable:

```
/paymethod/css/css.css
/paymethod/js/test.js
```

but not this

```
/paymethod/js/data.php
/paymethod/else/data.php
/paymethod/else/data.html
```

( those should work only server side, but they should not be accessed )

Since my Kohana framework already have this:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]
```

I added |paymethod , like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system|paymethod)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]
```

And it works, but this just restricts everything including css and js files.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this `.htaccess` in your `paymethod/` directory :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

Or in root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^paymethod/ - [L,F]
```

Comment: thanks. is it a must that it is inside paymethod/ ? can it not be in the root htaccess?

Comment: In my point of view it's better in `paymethod/`. But I added the global code.